# Swift 3 Add Long Press Gesture to Mapbox Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, uigesturerecognizer, mapbox

I'm trying to figure out how to add a Long press gesture to a map annotation(Mapbox).I have my code set up so that when a user tap's the annotation they segue to another view by putting my code in this function.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
}
```

Now I want to allow a user to segue to another view by holding the same annotation. I tried to use and if and else statement in the code above but the Long press gesture doesn't work unless I tap the annotation first to activate the function so the if and else statement can start working. But I dont want the user to tap then hold. I just want them to either tap or hold down on the annotation.

Thank You for your answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Mapbox API but if there's no proper delegate method try your own custom implementation with uigesturerecognizer and delegation.

set your gesture recognizer on the annotation view:

```
let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressDetected))
annotation.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
```

make a delegate

```
weak var delegate: AnnotationViewDelegate?
```

and a protocol `AnnotationViewDelegate` in Annotation subclass:

```
protocol AnnotationViewDelegate: class {
    func annotationDidDetectLongPress()
}
```

implement long press handler and notify the delegate about long tap inside

```
func longPressDetected(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    // here you should notify the delegate 
    delegate?.annotationDidDetectLongPress()
}
```

assign delegate to self in controller and implement

```
func annotationDidDetectLongPress() {
    // done
}
```

Comment: Seems like the Long press is getting added to the entire mapView and not just the annotationsView. And Also I get and error on the protocol.  Saying that protocol cannot be nested inside another declaration

Comment: @Markinson could you give a link to your repo so that I can check? It's pretty hard to guess if I don't see the code...